# How to reset variable a,b,c,and score after loop?

Tags: php, html, laravel

i want to count my score from option a/b/c that inputted from a form. for each input given, value from     a =1,b=2,c=3 ,after count i want to save the result in score variable

in my controller

```
public function score($id) {
    $user_login = Auth::user()->id;
    $answers = Answer::select('user_answer')->where('jenis_quiz_id','=',$id)->where('user_id','=',$user_login)->get();

    static $a = 0;
    static $b = 0;
    static $c = 0;
    static $score = 0;
    if($answers->count()) {
        foreach ($answers as $answer) {
            if ($answer->user_answer == '1') {
                $a++;
            } else if($answer->user_answer == '2') {
                $b++;
            } elseif($answer->user_answer == '3') {
                $c++;
            }
        }
    }

    $score = $a+$b+$c;
    $returnScore = $score;
    $a = null;
    $b = null;
    $c = null;
    $score = null;
    return $returnScore;
}


public function getShowResultOfQuiz($id) {
    $categoryquiz = JenisQuiz::findOrFail($id);
    $user = Auth::user()->id;

    $score= $this->score($id);

    $kelas = Auth::user()->kelas;
    $instansi = Auth::user()->instansi;

    History::create([
        'user_id'=>$user,
        'jenis_quiz_id'=>$id,
        'score'=> $score,
        'kelas' => $kelas,
        'instansi' => $instansi
    ]);

    // $time_taken = date("H:i:s", strtotime(Answer::whereJenisQuizId($id)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first()->time_taken));
    switch ($id) {
        case '1':
            return view('quiz1',compact('score','categoryquiz'));

        case '2':
            return view('quiz2',compact('score','categoryquiz'));

        case '3':
            return view('quiz3',compact('score','categoryquiz'));
    }
}
```

i want to reset a,b,c,and score variables every input submitted,and the problem is score always added from previous submitted answer instead of reset it before calculating the score again, help me , thanks

Comment: You don't need to set $a, $b, $c or $score to null. Also what's the point in assigning score to returnscore just to return it? Just `return $a+$b+$c` and don't assign those variables as static.

Comment: Also the if (count) is uneeded, you should use triple equals for comparisons always, and you're mixing elseif with else if. Your comparisons are also comparing int to string, and this would be better off as a switch statement.

Comment: There are many other problems with this, along with the fact that I don't know what the problem you want solving really is. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: i assign those to static because i want it declare the initial value of a,b,and c back to 0 every i submitted the form, thanks i will change it to switch statement instead...

Comment: how if i want to reset my score every time i take the quiz/submitted form? in my database i save my score and user_anwer

Comment: You don't need to assign them as static to make them reset to zero, just declare the values as zero before calculating like you're doing without the static keyword